# When running 2 HTML 5 adverts on a page they conflict, I've been told i need a unique identifier for each JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Morning. I'm completely new to JavaScript and have been thrown in the deep end with this. So sorry if what i'm asking is daft.

When running 2 html5 adverts on a webpage they are conflicting with each other as i have been told they have the same JavaScript code at the bottom. I've been told they need a anonymous function with a unique ID we can change for each advert we make.

Then I shouldn't really have a body tag at the bottom as that will conflict with a webpage as well. But when i change it to a div the advert doesn't display at all.

Could someone have a look and let me know what i need to change in the code to please. 
Cheers

```
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
// --- write your JS code here ---

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
images = images||{};

var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
exportRoot = new lib.Untitled1();

stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();
stage.enableMouseOver();

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}


</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <a href="$$URL$$" target="_blank">


<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" body style="background-     color:#ffffff"></canvas>
    </a>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to have 2 canvas for 2 adverts, isn't it?
So, you should try the following code.

```
<script>
var canvas1, canvas2, stage, exportRoot;

function init1() {
    // --- write your JS code here ---

    canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    images = images||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete1);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function init2() {

    canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    images = images||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete2);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}


function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete1(evt) {
    exportRoot = new lib.Untitled1();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas1);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function handleComplete2(evt) {
    exportRoot = new lib.Untitled1();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas2);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}


</script>

<body onload="init1();init2();">
    <a href="$$URL$$" target="_blank">

<canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="250" body style="background-     color:#ffffff"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="250" body style="background-     color:#ffffff"></canvas>
    </a>
 </body>
```

Comment: We are loading the adverts up to a ad server (Absolute banner manager) So there might be 20 adverts loaded on to the server at anyone go and they are displayed randomly. So we need to be able to put a unique name in for each advert we make so they wont conflict with another one that is on the page.

Comment: you should create 20 "canvas" node in the body (with unique ID, like canvas1, canvas2, canvas2, etc.) and different variables and functions (with suffix 1, 2, 3, etc.) and call each "initX" in onload of the body. Of course, a general procedure could be implemented, but it is more complicated

Comment: Please, try again the code above in my answer, I updated it again, tell me if it works

Comment: That works thank you, so i just need to add numbers to init - canvas - handlecomplete for each one to be different?

Comment: yes, exactly, you have to replicate variables, nodes, functions, etc, one for each canvas, just like the example I wrote

Comment: you're welcome :) please, vote my answer as solution :)